# Xamarin.Android Binding Library not generating classes - How to?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am trying to create Xamarin.Android binding library for `androidx.health:health-services-client`.  I have downloaded aar file from Maven and successfully generated a dll. But later I have found out that some classes are missing. For example, according to the google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active#check-capabilities)
There needs to be `MeasureCapabilities` class but this isnt generated.

```
HealthServicesClient healthClient = HealthServices.getClient(this /*context*/);
ListenableFuture<MeasureCapabilities> capabilitiesFuture =
        healthClient.getCapabilities();
Futures.addCallback(capabilitiesFuture,
        new FutureCallback<Capabilities>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@Nullable Capabilities result) {
                boolean supportsHeartRate = result
                        .supportedDataTypesMeasure()
                        .contains(DataType.HEART_RATE_BPM)
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // display an error
            }
        },
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this /*context*/));
```

I have checked Api.xml file generated and cannot find anything regarding this class. When look at the class definition on Android Studio.

```
package androidx.health.services.client.data

import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.health.services.client.proto.DataProto

/**
 * A place holder class that represents the capabilities of the
 * [androidx.health.services.client.MeasureClient] on the device.
 */
@Suppress("ParcelCreator")
public class MeasureCapabilities(
    /**
     * Set of supported [DataType] s for measure capture on this device.
     *
     * Some data types are not available for measurement; this is typically used to measure health
     * data (e.g. HR).
     */
    public val supportedDataTypesMeasure: Set<DataType>,
) : ProtoParcelable<DataProto.MeasureCapabilities>() {

    internal constructor(
        proto: DataProto.MeasureCapabilities
    ) : this(proto.supportedDataTypesList.map { DataType(it) }.toSet())

    /** @hide */
    override val proto: DataProto.MeasureCapabilities by lazy {
        DataProto.MeasureCapabilities.newBuilder()
            .addAllSupportedDataTypes(supportedDataTypesMeasure.map { it.proto })
            .build()
    }

    override fun toString(): String =
        "MeasureCapabilities(supportedDataTypesMeasure=$supportedDataTypesMeasure)"

    public companion object {
        @JvmField
        public val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<MeasureCapabilities> = newCreator { bytes ->
            val proto = DataProto.MeasureCapabilities.parseFrom(bytes)
            MeasureCapabilities(proto)
        }
    }
}
```

It looks to me nothing special here, class is public. Why wouldnt be generated at all?
Here is a minimum [repro](https://github.com/EmilAlipiev/Xamarin.Androidx.Health). you can clone and check. How to achieve this?

Comment: You could check the stops for how to bind an .aar library. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks but i already went through this i have tried all possible variations but somehow not getting this.